# why i pyqt5 tell me this widget does not exist if i know it does?

Tags: python, oop, error-handling, widget, pyqt5

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'messagerGUI.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
# ""

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import socket
import threading


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    header = 12
    connections = []
    ip = socket.gethostname()
    port = 1234
    connections_allowed = 3
    sock.bind((ip, port))
    sock.listen(connections_allowed)
    new_message = False

    def start(self):
        while True:
            self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
            threading.Thread(target=self.receive_data, args=[
                             self.conn], daemon=True).start()
            self.connections.append(self.conn)

    def receive_data(self, conn):
        self.reply = ""
        while True:
            try:

                message_lenth = conn.recv(self.header)
                lenth_of_message = message_lenth.decode("utf-8")

                if not message_lenth:
                    break

                elif message_lenth:
                    data = conn.recv(int(lenth_of_message))
                    self.reply = data.decode("utf-8")

                    print(self.reply)
                    self.new_message = True

                    for connection in self.connections:
                        if connection != conn:
                            connection.send(message_lenth.encode("utf-8"))
                            connection.send(self.reply.encode("utf-8"))

            except:
                break

    def packing_data_lenth(self, text):
        return len(text) * 4

    def send_data(self, data):
        try:
            for connection in self.connections:
                connection.send(
                    bytes(str(self.packing_data_lenth(data)), "utf-8"))
                connection.send(bytes(data, "utf-8"))
        except:
            pass


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        threading.Thread(target=self.start, daemon=True).start()
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(499, 367)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #113e4a;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(5)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.info = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.info.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.info.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.info.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(178, 357))
        self.info.setStyleSheet("background-color: #429178;\n"
                                "border-radius: 2px;")
        self.info.setObjectName("info")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.info)

        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.info)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(
            20, 317, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.info)

        self.message_widget()

        self.chat_area = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.chat_area.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.chat_area.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.chat_area.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(306, 0))
        self.chat_area.setStyleSheet("background-color: #429178;")
        self.chat_area.setObjectName("chat_area")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.chat_area)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(1)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.messages_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.chat_area)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.messages_area.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.messages_area.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.messages_area.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 259))
        self.messages_area.setStyleSheet("background-color: #113e4a;")
        self.messages_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.messages_area.setObjectName("messages_area")

        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 316))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(
            self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(
            QtWidgets.QLayout.SetNoConstraint)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")

        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(
            20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.messages_area.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.messages_area)

        self.input_area = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.chat_area)
        self.input_area.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.input_area.setObjectName("input_area")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.input_area)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.userInput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.input_area)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.userInput.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.userInput.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.userInput.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(22, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.userInput.setFont(font)
        self.userInput.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(17, 62, 74);\n"
                                     "color: #d0e8ce;\n"
                                     "border: 0px;")
        self.userInput.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.userInput.setFrame(True)
        self.userInput.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.userInput.setPlaceholderText("Type a message")
        self.userInput.setObjectName("userInput")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.userInput)
        self.sendButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.input_area)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.sendButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.sendButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.sendButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(12, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.sendButton.setFont(font)
        self.sendButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.sendButton.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.sendButton.setObjectName("sendButton")
        self.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.get_user_input)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.sendButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.input_area)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.chat_area)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

In this part(function message_widget) i get an error:

> self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
>   AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'scrollAreaWidgetContents'

Even though i did something similar in the get_user_input function,
i know the code is a mess but the only part that is not working is this part, 
the socket server and client are both working properly, i tested printing the 
text received in the terminal, so yeah, i wanna know why do i get this error?

```
    def message_widget(self):
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(158, 25))
        self.widget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #d35439;\n" "border-radius: 4px;")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.text(self.reply)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.widget)

    def get_user_input(self):
        self.user_msg = self.userInput.text()

        threading.Thread(target=self.send_data, args=[
                         self.user_msg], daemon=True).start()

        self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(
            self.widget_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(182, 25))
        self.widget_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.widget_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(236, 172, 55);\n"
                                    "border-radius: 4px;")
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget_2)
        self.label_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(
            QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_2.setText(self.user_msg)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.widget_2)
        self.userInput.setText("")

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PadoMessager"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Server"))
        self.sendButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send"))
        self.sendButton.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Return"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *think* it exists, but when you call `message_widget()` it does not exist yet.

In fact, you are calling that function *before* this line:

```
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
```

So, it *could* work if you put that function at least *after* creating that widget.

Unfortunately, there are other serious issues with your code.

The most important one is that you are modifying the output of pyuic to create your program, which is highly discouraged (and the `WARNING` message at the beginning should be a hint).

The python scripts generated from UI files should **NEVER** be edited, but used as an import in your actual program files. The most obvious reason is that as soon as you want to do some changes in the ui, you'll find yourself in the mess of trying to merge the new generated code with what you've written so far.

To know more about this, read the documentation about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Other issues in your code:

- threading in Qt should be used with Qt's own QThread as much as possible;
- UI objects should *never* be accessed nor modified by an external thread; to do that you have to use a QThread, and communicate with the main Qt thread using signals and slots;
- `QLabel.text()` does not accept parameters, as it is used to access the text property; to set the text of a label, use `setText()`;

Comment: You're welcome, but I'd settle for a simple check to the accepted flag on my answer instead ;-)